# FBAudienceNetwork in iMessage Extension

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, imessage, facebook-audience-network

I added a mma Banner in a iMessage Extension. But nothing happens when I touch the ad. The console logs this exception:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:view] called!
```

This is the code to load the ad

```
let adView = FBAdView(placementID: "some ids", adSize: kFBAdSize320x50, rootViewController: self)
adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: adView.frame.size.width, height: adView.frame.size.height)
adView.delegate = self
adView.loadAd()
```

It's version 4.15.0 from FBAudienceNetwork.framework

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: It's not possible since UIApplication.shared.openUrl is not available :(

Comment: @zeiteisen, it looks like the openUrl method was updated to iOS 10 in the latest release (4.17.0) - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x/

Comment: @zeiteisen you can use UIApplication.shared.openUrl in your imessage extention by enable exention api to yes